# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column created_at and updated_at column missing

Tags: laravel

I'm encountering error like SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `buildings` (`building_name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Building Four, 2017-10-12 02:56:13, 2017-10-12 02:56:13)). but i don't have a updated_at and created_at column in my database how come these columns shows up in the error?

BuildingRepository.php

```
  <?php


namespace App\Repositories\Building;
use App\Building;


interface BuildingRepository
{
    public function getById($id);

    public function getAll();

    public function create(array $attributes); 

    public function update($id, array $attributes);

    public function delete($id);

}
```

EloquentBuilding.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Repositories\Building;

use \App\Building;

class EloquentBuilding implements BuildingRepository
{   
    private $model;

    public function __construct(Building $model)
    {   
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        return $this->model->findOrFail($id);
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->model->all();
    }

    public function create(array $attributes)
    {
        return $this->model->fill($attributes)->save();
    }

    public function update($id, array $attributes)
    {

    }

    public function delete($id)
    {

    }


}
```

BuildingController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Building;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\Building\BuildingRepository;

class BuildingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    private $building;


    public function __construct(BuildingRepository $building)
    {
        $this->building = $building;
    }

    public function createBuilding()
    {
       return view('building.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $this->validate($request, array(
           'building_name'=>'required',
           'building_information'=>'required',
       ));


        $buildings = array('building_name' => $request->building_name,
                            'building_inforamtion' => $request->building_information);


        $this->building->create($buildings);

    }

    public function getAllBuilding()
    {
        $buildings =  $this->building->getAll();
        return view('building.show')->with('buildings', $buildings);
    }

    public function getSpecificRecord()
    {
        $buildings = $this->building->getById(1);
        return view('building.show')->with('buildings', $buildings);
    }
}
```

Building.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Building extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'building_name', 'building_information', 'building_image', 
    ];
}
```

Comment: try `public $timestamps = false;` in your model `Building.php`

Comment: @NitishKumar thanks it works, now how can i make one of my columns nullable?

Comment: You can define the same in the migration.

Comment: yeah i define it then i use migrate:rollback then migrate it again, thanks again.

Comment: @NitishKumar im newbie here, i am wondering how did i manage to connect my buildingcontroller to the eloquentbuilding?

Comment: You need to have a clear concept on `interface`, `abstract class`, extending the class and implementing the interface, there lot of tutorials available online.

Answer (score 11):

By default, Eloquent expects `created_at` and `updated_at` columns to exist in your tables. If you do not wish to have these columns to be automatically managed by Eloquent, then you need to set the `$timestamps` property in your model to `false`. Your file `Building.php` should look like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Building extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'building_name', 'building_information', 'building_image', 
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default Eloquent expects `created_at` & `updated_at` columns in all your tables. You can set `$timestamps` property to `false`.

To make a column nullable, you mention that in your migration. For example, I want to make address column of my table nullable, I do this.

> $table->string('address')->nullable();

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
The problem was that the column name that I mentioned inside migration was not same as what I was using inside my controller, model and view.
So, I would suggest that you check whether you have taken same column name inside the migration that you are further using for mass assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Turn places `created_at`   and   `updated_at` from the database

[image]